# Command Prompt- The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: directory, command, prompt

My command in the cmd is as follows:

```
cd C:\Users\khalha\Desktop
```

and I get the error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

It seems the issue is with that I am missing the desktop folder in my users folder, any recommendations on how I should move forward?
However, I am unable to also change my directory in general, not just do desktop

[image]

Comment: What folder are you in when you execute that? If you're not on the C: drive, then you need to use `cd /d` instead of `cd` only. Also, do you have a user named *khalha*? Can you see the folder in Windows Explorer? Details help.

Comment: I opened the command prompt from the start menu and now wrote the following command: cd/d C:\Users\khalha\Desktop, still receiving the same error

Comment: It's `cd /d` (note the space). Again, can you see that folder using Windows Explorer? Do you actually have a user named *khalha* on that machine whose user folder you can browse to in Explorer? I asked three questions, and you ignored two of them. Please [edit] your question and **be specific**.

Comment: @KenWhite my username is khalha but I do not see it in the windows explorer, I tried to use the command cd Desktop before but that did not work and I was told that I have to specify the path more.

Comment: If you can't see `C:\Users\khalha` in Explorer, then you can't `cd` into that folder from the command prompt either. The directory has to actually be there first.

Comment: @KenWhite in windows explorer, desktops directory, simply says Desktop. So in the command prompt I originally tried cd Desktop, but was receiving the same error

Comment: You're not paying attention. Open Explorer. Expand the C: drive, find the *Users* folder, and then expand that folder. Do you see a folder within *Users* for *khalha* there? And if you do, can you browse into it?

Comment: @KenWhite Oh, yes I did find khalha and am able to browse into it!

Comment: OK. When you open the command prompt from the start menu, what is the text you see inside that command window *exactly*?

Comment: @KenWhite its says microsoft windows version 6.1.7601 along with copy right stuff
and then underneath it is
C:\Users\khalha>

Comment: Then `cd desktop` (notice no other text, no backslash, no drive letter, nothing but **cd desktop**) and hit Enter.

Comment: @KenWhite I just tried it and received the same error, that was the original command I had tried and was getting the same error.

Comment: None of that makes sense. If you're at a command prompt that says `C:\Users\khalha`, and there is a `Desktop` folder below that (which you say there is in Explorer), then that `cd desktop` works fine. If it's not working for you, then you've not been truthful in all of the previous comments here.

Comment: @KenWhite I am not sure what to say, I have no reason to not be telling the truth and followed what you said closely. I do appreciate the help though, maybe it is some IT issue with my computer.

Comment: @KenWhite Are you saying that desktop has to be under the user file khalha, there is a shortcut for desktop in the khalha folder in the windows explorer

Comment: I asked you if there was a *folder* in C:\Users\khalha for the desktop, and you said *Yes*. A shortcut isn't a folder.

Comment: @KenWhite, Oh my apologies, there is no folder labeled desktop in there.

Comment: Then you (or your IT department) have configured it to be elsewhere. Are you using roaming profiles (where you can log in at any computer and see your desktop the same, with all the same shortcuts)?

Comment: @KenWhite, yes, I had transferred computers recently and alot of my files were transported between computers through a USB. I have also posted an image of my window explorer as an answer below if that helps.

Comment: @KenWhite Okay, any recommendations of what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Desktop folder by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that you don't have any wrong paths with any Windows specified type files in `Registry Editor`.

I just had this problem because I had a `.bat` file running in regedit at *this* path but moved that file without changing it's path in regedit.  It produces `The system cannot find the path specified.` because if you move a startup file without also changing its path in regedit, then it will fail to find the file.

Answer (score -2):

save your folder in Windows(C:) files. It will work.